# Adding "xmlns" namespace with and without prefix

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-namespaces

I'm working on C# class I want to serialize, everything goes fine except i'm getting crazy obtaining namespaces of my root element as follows:

```
<m:DE815 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:m="http://das.dogane.finanze.it"   xmlns="http://das.dogane.finanze.it" versione="1.0">
```

I need to write inside root element both xmlns="http://das.dogane.finanze.it" and xmlns:m="http://das.dogane.finanze.it" but what I obtain is this:

```
<m:DE815 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:m="http://das.dogane.finanze.it" versione="1.0">
```

Here's the code I use to serialize my class:

```
            stream = new MemoryStream(); // read xml in memory

            XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DE815), "http://das.dogane.finanze.it");

            List<XmlQualifiedName> names = new List<XmlQualifiedName>();

            var xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(names.ToArray());
            xmlns.Add("m", "http://das.dogane.finanze.it");
            xmlns.Add("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            xmlns.Add("", "http://das.dogane.finanze.it");
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, de815, xmlns); // read object

            int count = (int)stream.Length; // saves object in memory stream

            byte[] arr = new byte[count];
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            stream.Read(arr, 0, count);
            UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding(); // convert byte array to string

            String xmlAsString = utf.GetString(arr).Trim();

            File.WriteAllText("d:\\prova_DE815.xml", xmlAsString, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Here's the declaration of the class I want to serialize:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")
System.SerializableAttribute()
System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://das.dogane.finanze.it", AnonymousType=true)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://das.dogane.finanze.it", IsNullable=false)
public partial class DE815 {
```

What am I missing on the code?

Thanks in advance for your help, feel free to ask more questions if I missed any information.

Comment: You need to put the namespace attributes in the properties (not above the classes)  You put [XmlRoot(namespace)] above classes.  On properties in the classes use [XmlElement(Namespace=)] or [XmlAttribute(Namespace=)]

Comment: Hello jdweng, you mean instead of using "XmlRootAttribute" as shown above, should I use "XmlElement" or "XmlAttribute"? where should i use these properties?

Comment: Consider I don't want to add any namespace definition to my inner elements

Comment: You have to if they are different from the class (parent xml tag).